# Summing values only if date has passed

Tags: google-sheets

I have 13 columns of data (money to be received), and each column has a corresponding date (the date on which the money will be received).

Each column of data has the corresponding date to the immediate right of the data column.

I want to do a sum of all the values in a particular row for which the corresponding date has passed.

For example, if there are 3 data columns, and the date for column 1 and 3 have passed (and not the date for column 2), then it will only sum column 1 and 3 (NOT column 2).

How can I do this? Can I do it with existing functions or do I need to use script editor? Please provide script if needed.

Comment: Just tried it, it won't work because SUMIFS will only sum if ALL criteria is met. For Data1 shouldn't be summed if Date1 < TODAY() is false, and that would break the sum for the other values, regardless of their dates.

Comment: Yes it is tricky because neither the dates nor the sums of money are in a continuous range within each row. Prob need an array formula with use of odd/even to decide if the current column is a date or an amount, or offset 2 columns at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not pretty, I would approach this with a series of nested formulas:

```
=sum(sumif(C2:C, "<"&TODAY(), B2:B), sumif(E2:E, "<"&TODAY(), D2:D), sumif(G2:G, "<"&TODAY(), F2:F),[On for all 13 sets of data])
```

This assumes columns C, E, and G are the dates and the items to be summed are in the column prior to each date.  Copy the SUMIF() portion for each of your columns.

Comment: Definitely not pretty, but it does the job in a manner that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the sumproduct version would be something like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISEVEN(COLUMN(A2:G10)-COLUMN(A2))*(B2:H10>J2)*A2:G10)
```

where the data is in cols A:H and the criterion date is in J2

[image]